# When, how & who first gave this calculation of $\pi$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, math-history, transcendental-numbers

I came across this interesting method to calculate $\pi$. Why is it true and who first presented it?

To calculate $\pi$, multiply by $4$, the product of fractions formed by using, as the numerators. the sequence of primes $> 2$ ..i.e. $3,5,7,11,13,17$ etc and use as denominators the multiple of $4$ that is closest to the numerator and you will get as accurate value of $\pi$ that you like. In other words,

$$
\frac \pi 4 = \frac 3 4 \cdot \frac 5 4 \cdot \frac 7 8 \cdot \frac{11}{12} \cdot \frac{13}{12} \cdot \frac{17}{16}\cdots
$$

Comment: I suspect Euler. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Euler, I suppose.

Comment: i believe it is john wallis, an english mathematician.

Comment: @abel - John Wallis is responsible for a similar but different formula which does not involve primes, see my answer, and here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product

Comment: @nbubis, you are right. i didn't realize the numerators were all primes. i have john valis' arithmetica, i should check.

Comment: I think this question would be more appropriately asked at [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 9):

This  result is due to Euler, in a paper published in $1744$, entitled "*Variae observationes circa series infinitas*".

An English translation of the paper may be found [here](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/docs/translations/E072en.pdf), and the quoted result on page $11$ in that link.

[image]

The proof follows from the series expansion for $\arctan$, giving:
$$\frac{\pi}{4}=1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}-\ldots$$
So that:
$$\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{15}-\frac{1}{21}+\ldots$$
Adding the two together, we get rid of the $1/3, 1/9$ and all other multiples of $1/3$.
$$\frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{\pi}{4} = \left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)\frac{\pi}{4}
=1+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{11}+\ldots$$
 Repeat the same trick to get rid of the $1/5, 1/10, 1/15$ etc.:
$$\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{\pi}{4} = \left(1-\frac{1}{5}\right)\frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}
=1-\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{13}+\ldots$$
If you continue this sequence, all compound factors get removed, and you are left with only with prime values in the denominator, and either one above or one below the prime in the numerator:
$$\cdots\frac{12}{11}\cdot\frac{8}{7}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{\pi}{4} = 1$$
Inverting gives the desired result:
$$\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{4}\cdot\frac{7}{8}\cdot\frac{11}{12}\cdot\ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_%CF%80) attributes it to Euler, but they don't have a reference to any resource. It's hard to google a formula, so I had to search for "pi identities" and "Euler pi identities." I checked a handful of more sites and they all ascribe the identity to Euler. But I can't find any information on the date or publication/letter where this identity first appears.